# Play 2.4 Adding Module instead of Plugin

Tags: playframework, dependency-injection, module

I have a Play 2.3 app that I'm migrating to Play 2.4 and I'm working on one of the warnings which is about migrating the plugin's to modules. I'm following this documentation here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PluginsToModules

I have now a couple of questions in my application that has some Akka actors. So far here is what I did with the plugins:

```
  class MyPlugin extends Plugin {

    // I get the current Application
    val app = play.api.Play.current

    // On start of the plugin, I call my initializers
    def onStart: Unit = {
      super.onStart()
      doInitialize(app)
    }
  }
```

Now in my doInitialize routine, I do the initialization of the different services that I need. I later expose these services as a trait and I mix this trait on the places where I need the service references. So for example., my controller looks like:

```
object Application extends Controller with MyServices {

  ....
}
```

where MyServices is

```
trait MyServices {

  def myActorRef: ActorRef
  ...
  ...
}
```

How should this setup now be migrated to using Modules with little impact to the overall application? It is also not clear as to where I should put my onStart method contents when I migrate from Plugin to Module!

Edit: I tried the following:

```
sealed trait MyComp
class MyCompImpl @Inject() (lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) extends MyComp {
  val application = MyConfig(play.api.Play.current)

  // initialize upon start
  Initializer.doInitialize(application)

  // destroy upon stop
  lifecycle.addStopHook(() => {
    Future.successful { Initializer.destroyConfig(application) }
  })
}
```

I have the module defined as below:

```
class MyModule extends Module {

  override def bindings(environment: play.api.Environment, configuration: Configuration): Seq[Binding[_]] = {
    logger.info(s"registering bindings")
    Seq(
      bind[MyComp].to[MyCompImpl].eagerly()
    )
  }
}
```

This now fails with the reason:

CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
  at com.config.MyCompImpl.<init>(MyModule.scala:25)
  while locating com.config.MyCompImpl
```

It is becoming a pain in the *** with each upgrade to a Play application's to newer versions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take in to account one more change in 2.4: "[Removing GlobalSettings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings)":

> Anything that needs to happen on start up should now be happening in
>   the constructor of a dependency injected class. A class will perform
>   its initialisation when the dependency injection framework loads it.
>   If you need eager initialisation (because you need to execute some
>   code before the application is actually started), define an eager
>   binding.

on this page - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PluginsToModules -  you have:

```
bind[MyComponent].to[MyComponentImpl]
```

in your example you need to use

```
bind[MyComponent].to[MyComponentImpl].asEagerSingleton
```

and the code `doInitialize(app)` must be run in the constructor of `MyComponentImpl` like

```
class MyComponentImpl extends MyComponent {
  initialize() 
  def initialize() = {
     //initialize your app
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What if I need access to the Play frameworks underlying Application object during start up? How should I get that injected? I have edited my question with what I have tried! could you please take a look and comment on that?

Comment: did you try to inject application like "sparkr" says ? well, it was you :)

Comment: Yes, I ate my own dog food! Anyways, thanks for participating!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this as below:

```
sealed trait MyComp
class MyCompImpl @Inject() (app: Application, lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) extends MyComp {
  val application = Myconfig(app)

  // initialize upon start
  Initializer.doInitialize(application)

  // destroy upon stop
  lifecycle.addStopHook(() => {
    Future.successful { Initializer.destroyConfig(application) }
  })
}
```