# Play framework Plugin is replaced with Module,

Tags: mongodb, playframework, guice

In Play framework Plugin is replaced with Module, 
My question is how can I implement onStart () and onStop() methods in module.
Because I have used a plugin to initialize mongodb instance with  onStart () method, But Modules does not providing these facility. How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play 2.4 Adding Module instead of Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195850/play-2-4-adding-module-instead-of-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PluginsToModules:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait MyComponent

class MyComponentImpl @Inject()(lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) extends MyComponent {
  // previous contents of Plugin.onStart
  lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    // previous contents of Plugin.onStop
    Future.successful(())
  }
}
```